# MuleEvent event.getFlowVariable vs. event.getMessage().getInvocationProperty

Tags: mule

What is the difference between these two for `MuleEvent event` that gets passed to the `MessageProcessor`: `event.getFlowVariable` vs. `event.getMessage().getInvocationProperty`. I tested and they give the same result even for async (I tested by calling it in a scatter-gather with different variable value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is basically any difference. In fact flowVariables named invocationProperty at message level are copied in the mule event when the message is set so that you can also access it from there via the getFlowVariable methods.
This is an extract of the MuleDefaultEvent.class setMessage method that shows you that values are just the same.

```
@Override
public void setMessage(MuleMessage message)
{
    this.message = message;
    if (message instanceof DefaultMuleMessage)
    {
        // Don't copy properties from message to event every time we copy event as we did before. Rather
        // only copy invocation properties over if MuleMessage had invocation properties set on it before
        // MuleEvent was created.
        flowVariables.putAll(((DefaultMuleMessage) message).getOrphanFlowVariables());

        ((DefaultMuleMessage) message).setInvocationProperties(flowVariables);
        if (session instanceof DefaultMuleSession)
        {
            ((DefaultMuleMessage) message).setSessionProperties(((DefaultMuleSession) session).getProperties());
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Regards

Comment: Thank you for the extract. I'm glad they are basically the same values. It's pretty awesome that you could trace down to that code.

Comment: You welcome. I just took advantage of Eclipse/Anypoint Studio shortcut ctrl+shift+T (Open Type) and typed in the class name like DefaultMuleEvent. Once you are able to read the sources everything become easier. Off course will not work for enterprise libraries :-)